# движение персонажа вместе с движущейся платформой unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

подскажите, как заставить персонажа двигаться вместе с платформой, на которой он стоит? пробовал припарентить - ничего не меняется, платформа уезжает из-под перса, и он падает.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rules : MonoBehaviour
    {

    public GameObject firstCard; //ссылка на платформу

    void Start()
    {
        firstCard.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("firstCard"); //запускаем анимацию движения платформы (едет вперед-назад)
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) //триггеры тоже не робят
    {//должно припарентить перса к платформе, чтоб он двигался вместе с ней
        if (col.gameObject.name.Equals ("3ofDiamonds"))
            this.transform.parent = col.transform;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name.Equals ("3ofDiamonds"))
            this.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

коллайдеры есть и на персе и на платформе, на персе еще ригидбоди

Comment: Можно, к примеру, сделать префаб копья с компонентами коллайдера и твердого тела. Настройить. А по нажатию кнопки "метнуть копье" создавать экземплар такого префаба где-нибудь справа вверху камеры (раз уж от первого лица). И после создания метаем это копье (например, AddForce()). Если настроить все правильно, то в полете на копье будет действовать сила притяжения, и копье полетит по дуге

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте припарентить(стартовую точку лифта, и конечную. Но после того как вы припарентили  конечную точку удалите объект) затем дабавьте NavMeshAgent. И что бы когда персонаж заходил в область лифта, NavMeshAgent выключался. А лифт можно двигать transform.Translate